# How do I get the IP address of an LXC container for automation?

Tags: lxc, lxd

How can I get the IP address of an LXC container in a format I can use in scripting?

Right now, the command `lxc info <container>` report that information, but in a human readable format, with a lot of information.

I would like to ONLY to **GET** the IP address given a container name.

**Note**: I **HAVE** to duplicate [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269588/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-of-an-lxc-container) because Linux Containers have changed a lot.

Installing **lxd** and using unprivileged containers is the default way to go this days (2017) and I think the solutions posted on the original question are do not resolve the issue in this case.

In any case, I installed the package **lxc1** to get access to the command `lxc-info`, but that command doesn't recognize any of my unprivileged containers.

Answer (score 5):

A native solution (which isn't any prettier than @siloko's answer) would be

```
lxc list "<name>" -c 4 | awk '!/IPV4/{ if ( $2 != "" ) print $2}'
```

There are alternatives to `awk`, but that's tangential to the question.

Comment: Works well for multiple IP addresses

Answer (score 4):

So far this is the easiest way:

```
lxc list -c4 --format csv <container> | cut -d' ' -f1
```

But maybe it will be possible [without `cut`](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/4785).

**EDIT:** Uncut bash:

```
a=( $(lxc list -c4 --format csv u1) ) ip4=$a[1] echo $ip4
```

Hint from @monstermunchkin from the above issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
lxc list | grep nameofthecontainer | egrep -o "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"
```

This is what I am using,  I pass the container name in as a variable.

Comment: the `grep` command is unneded, you can put directly  `lxc list container_name | egrep -o "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"` with the same result

Answer (score 2):

*pylxd* is the official python API client interface [developed, supported, and endorsed](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/rest-api/#api-clients) by the LXD project.

Installation instructions [here](https://pylxd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installation)

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
>>> from pylxd import Client
>>> client = Client()
>>> for p in client.containers.all(): print(p.name, p.state().network['eth0']['addresses'][0]['address'])
... 
stretch-cc 10.76.67.242
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit ugly but:

```
lxc-info -n my-container | grep IP: | tr -d ' ' | cut -f2 -d:
```

will get you just the IP address

Comment: Thank you. It would be a solution in the near time. BTW, the idea is to use the command `lxc info`, not `lxc-info` as they are different how I explained.

Comment: bare `lxc` is not available on my system (Ubuntu 16.04), sorry.

Answer (score 0):

These use a single `grep`.

For IPv4:

```
lxc info container-name |grep -Po '\seth\d:\sinet\s+\K[0-9\.]+'
```

For IPv6 (will probably list multiple IPs):

```
lxc info container-name |grep -Po '\seth\d:\sinet6\s+\K[0-9a-f:]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `jq`:

```sh
sudo apt-get install jq
```

The function `get_lxc_container_ip` has 4 arguments:

- arg1: container name
- arg2(optional): family, `inet`(default) or `inet6`
- arg3(optional): interface, default values are both `eth0` and `enp5s0`
- arg4(optional): scope, `global`(default), `link` or `local`

Exit status:

- 0: success
- 4: no valid result
- 1 (not likely): jq last output value was either `false` or `null`
- 2 (not likely): jq usage problem or system error
- 3 (not likely): jq program compile error

```shell
get_lxc_container_ip() {
    local container=$1
    local family=${2:-inet}
    local interface=\"${3:-'eth0", "enp5s0'}\"
    local scope=${4:-global}
    lxc list --format json |
        jq -re 'try .[] | select (.name == "'"$container"'") 
            | .state.network | to_entries[]
            | select(.key == ('"$interface"')).value.addresses[]
            | select((.family == "'"$family"'") and (.scope == "'"$scope"'"))
            | .address'
}
```

Since a container can create many interfaces (e.g. run docker/lxd inside the container with security.nesting=true), other ways based on text filtering may get inaccurate result. jq does not have this problem.

Be aware that some interfaces may have multiple IP addresses (e.g. family=inet6 and scope=global), you may need to pipe it to `head -1` to get the first result.

Answer (score -1):

```
lxc-info --name container --ips --no-humanize
```

prints the container IP addresses.

The returned value is a **list** because a container can have more than one address.